# Problem using eventhandler to show video on subpage according to which image was clicked on mainpage (html, javascript , css)

Tags: javascript, onclick, event-listener

I'm a noob in html, css and javascript and i'm making a project for my students.
I've made a main page called index.html and a subpage called visningsside.html (pardon the danish) and linked to external CSS and Javascript (which works fine).
I want two images called film1 and film2 to tricker a function, when clicked. The function should, according to which image was clicked, load an iframe with embeded-link to youtube on the subpage, and change the page to show the sub page.
The page changes, when the images are clicked, but the iframe isn't changing.
I'm using replit as editor.

You can see, comment, edit and run the project at [replit](https://replit.com/join/phoxeshbeg-anne-sofie-haun)

I've tried to add DOMContentLoaded to the script in order to avoid problems with html-elements not loaded before the script executes. Perhaps i should try to use onclick instead of an eventlistener, but i thought it was nice to use event target as a parameter to determine which image was clicked.

Comment: Please post the code that cause the problem...
script and html.
Read this to improve your question : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's overcomplicated, and not good style to use the iframes. When the Javascript attempts to set the source of an element with id "video-player", there is no such element in the document where the javascript is functioning. You'd need to somehow get that info into the iframe; I don't remember how to do that exactly, but the better thing would be to just have a  where you could put the video within the same document I think.